# maven-assembly-plugin not packaging dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I've used maven-assembly-plugin to package dependencies into a single jar in other projects, however in my current project the jar with dependencies is not being created and I'm stumped as to why. In other projects I will see two jar's generated   `xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`, but in this project just the `xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` file is being generated.

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.sk</groupId>
  <artifactId>gt_tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>gt_tutorial</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <geotools.version>20-RC</geotools.version>
    <jts.version>1.16.0-RC1</jts.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-grid</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
      <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jts.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-363 support as recommended for GeoTools 20 http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
      <artifactId>systems-common-java8</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.2</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net repository</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>osgeo</id>
      <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>boundless</id>
      <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <inherited>true</inherited>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>
                      org.sk.Grid4
                    </mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>



      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Move the execution definition of the maven-assembly-plugin out of the pluginManagement part. which means into `<project><build><plugins>..</plugins></build></project>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is, you have defined assembly plugin only within `<pluginmanagement/>`.

> pluginManagement is an element that is seen along side plugins.
>   Plugin Management contains plugin elements in much the same way,
>   except that rather than configuring plugin information for this
>   particular project build, it is intended to configure project builds
>   that inherit from this one. However, this only configures plugins that
>   are actually referenced within the plugins element in the children or
>   in the current POM. The children have every right to override
>   pluginManagement definitions.

While  `<plugins/>` is an actual invocation of the plugin. It may or may not be inherited from a `<pluginManagement/>`.   Hence it should be called like within `<build/>` directly:

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
              .....
      </execution>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```